# C# Using JSON.NET to get list

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Say you have a string like this:

```
{
    "inventory1": {
        "confirmed": 1,
        "items": [{
            "id": "42",
            "ammount": "2"
        }, {
            "id": "41",
            "ammount": "3"
        }]
    },
    "inventory2": {
        "confirmed": 1,
        "items": [{
            "id": "43",
            "ammount": "1"
        }, {
            "id": "41",
            "ammount": "2"
        }]
    }
}
```

How can I get the ids for each of the items in inventory1 into a list of string?

Comment: Use a POCO mapping and deserialize to that, or use JObject/JArray, or even `dynamic` - of which there is [*no shortage of examples*](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm). After this first "how can I access" is understood then the extraction itself is rather trivial, say with LINQ or even a manual loop. In any case, no code/attempt -> no issue/problem, only a task. Please consult documentation and previous questions on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var ids = JToken.Parse(json)
                .SelectToken("inventory1.items")
                .Select(item => item["id"].ToString())
                .ToList();
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vadl3I

Answer (score 0):

Paste your JSON to [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), then create the suggested classes in your project. Then you can deserialize your JSON and get any specific part easily :

```
var myDeserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(myJsonString);
List<Item> result = myDeserializedJson.inventory1
                                      .items
                                      .Select(o => o.id)
                                      .ToList();
```

Or if you don't want to create mapping classes, you can load it to `JObject` and use property indexer to get specific JSON property :

```
var result = JObject.Parse(myJsonString)["inventory1"]["items"]
                    .Select(o => o["id"].ToString())
                    .ToList();
```